# jQuery each through elements collecting data value and using condition for right output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a little bit of a problem looping through HTML elements, collecting the value from data-points and checking if the passed value is less than to select and show the correct heading.

```js
var percentageScore = "43";

$('.quiz-score .final-result').each(function(index) {
  if (percentageScore <= $(this).data('points')) {
    var finalStatus = $(this).find('h3').text();
    $('.final-score').text(finalStatus);
  }
});
```

```css
.final-result { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quiz-score">
  <div class="final-result" data-points="20">
    <h3>
      under 20
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="final-result" data-points="40">
    <h3>
      between 21 and 40
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="final-result" data-points="60">
    <h3>
      between 41 and 60
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="final-result" data-points="80">
    <h3>
     between 61 and 80
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="final-result" data-points="100">
    <h3>
      between 81 and 100
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="final-score"></div>
```

Comment: That code is working as expected, do you want to show the first occurence?

Comment: It seems to always show the 100 points result, if you see the percentageScore var i am setting at 43, it should be showing "between 41 and 60" but whatever the set percentageScore it always shows the last one 81 to 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to break the loop.

To break a `$.each()` loop, return `false`.

From [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

> Use `return false` to break out of `each()` loops early.

```js
var percentageScore = "43";

$('.quiz-score .final-result').each(function(index) {
  if (percentageScore <= $(this).data('points')) {
    var finalStatus = $(this).find('h3').text();
    $('.final-score').text(finalStatus);
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
.final-result { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quiz-score">
  <div class="final-result" data-points="20">
    <h3>
      under 20
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="final-result" data-points="40">
    <h3>
      between 21 and 40
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="final-result" data-points="60">
    <h3>
      between 41 and 60
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="final-result" data-points="80">
    <h3>
     between 61 and 80
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="final-result" data-points="100">
    <h3>
      between 81 and 100
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="final-score"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, knew I had it cracked and was something simple! thanks for the helping hand!

Comment: Not a problem. The official docs are a good source. Don't forget to have a look when possible: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 1):

If you need to stop at the first occurence, you need to break the function `each` returning `false`;

The function `each` is not stopping, so every points value greater than `43` will be considered and the last one is `between 81 and 100`.

```js
var percentageScore = "43";

$('.quiz-score .final-result').each(function(index) {
  if (percentageScore <= $(this).data('points')) {
    var finalStatus = $(this).find('h3').text();
    $('.final-score').text(finalStatus);
    return false; // <--- HERE!
  }
});
```

```css
.final-result { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quiz-score">
  <div class="final-result" data-points="20">
    <h3>
      under 20
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="final-result" data-points="40">
    <h3>
      between 21 and 40
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="final-result" data-points="60">
    <h3>
      between 41 and 60
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="final-result" data-points="80">
    <h3>
     between 61 and 80
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="final-result" data-points="100">
    <h3>
      between 81 and 100
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="final-score"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, knew I had it cracked and was something simple! thanks for the helping hand!